# Text Field History in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, textfield, scenebuilder

I am looking for a way to somehow store the text entered into the textfield created in FXML file by Scenebuilder for the entire session.

Ex:User Logs in to the application and then enter the Text to textfield to search for the data. I want to make it like when we place the mouse in the Text Field it shows the search executed in this session.

I looked for tutorials ,I couldn't find. Can anyone guide me to the tutorial link if it's there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like what you need is an editable ComboBox.  Every time a search is executed, add the value in the ComboBox to the list in the ComboBox:

```
public class SearchHistorySample extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        ComboBox<String> comboBox = new ComboBox<>();
        comboBox.setEditable(true);
        comboBox.setMinWidth(200);
        Button button = new Button("Search");
        Text text = new Text("No Search Yet");
        button.setOnAction(evt -> {
            text.setText("You searched for: " + comboBox.getValue());
            comboBox.getItems().add(comboBox.getValue());
            comboBox.setValue("");
        });
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(new VBox(5, new HBox(10, comboBox, button), text), 300, 200));
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```